# How to acces attributes of a structure using pybind?

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I'm using pybind to wrap some C++ functions and then use it in Python. I need some structures but I don't know how to access in Python to its attributes. My structures don't have methods only attributes so I think the binding is like this (maybe this is also wrong):

```
py::class_<Struct_Sample>(m, "Struct_Sample");
```

And this is the struct:

```
typedef struct Struct_Sample
{
   float time_ms;
   float frequency_mhz;
} Struct_Sample;
```

How can I access to the attributes in python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/latest/classes.html#instance-and-static-fields) you can use `def_readwrite`:

```
py::class_<Struct_Sample>(m, "Struct_Sample")
    .def_readwrite("time_ms", &Struct_Sample::time_ms);
```